# Do all "events" in the context of programming are asynchronized?

Tags: java, events

In my application, I will log some special lines to indicate some state changes, e.g.

```
logger.info("Read file abc.txt completed from upstream system");
logger.info("The content of file abc.txt is valid");
logger.info("The content of abc.txt has been saved to db");
```

Then I monitor the log file, and when found any line of above, I create an instance of "Event" for them:

```
class NewFileEvent() {}
class ValidationEvent() {}
class PersistEvent() {}

while(true) {
    String nextLine = readNextLineFromLog();
    if("Read file abc.txt completed from upstream system".equals(nextLine)) {
        return new NewFileEvent();
    } else if("The content of file abc.txt is valid".equals(nextLine)) {
        return new ValidationEvent();
    } else if("The content of abc.txt has been saved to db".equals(nextLine)) {
        return new PersistEvent();
    }
}
```

But when my friend reviewed my code, he said I should not call it "event" since it's not "asynchronized". When he see the name `event`, he is expecting it to come from another thread, but in my code, I just parse it in a loop one by one.

I'm puzzuled now. When we say something is `event` in programming, do we assume it "asynchronized"? So there is no "synchronous" events?

Comment: No. Your friend has a specific event type in mind and assumes that all events are of this type. This is just wrong. An event is something that happens. Many events are single-threaded, synchronous events. See swing for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event is just an object. The question is, if sending/receiving/processing events is synchronous or asynchronous. Or in other words: Does the method, that is used for sending an event, block, until the event has been processed, or does it return immediately? And, if two events have been 'sent', are they processed in parallel or sequentially?

In Java, events are usually processed by event listeners, so you register an event listener somewhere which acts as a callback that gets notified as soon as the event occures. This is usually NOT asynchronous, so the events are delivered to all listeners one after the other within the same thread. Multi threading is not suggested in that case. It usually has no advantage and makes everything much more complex and error prone.

Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

So the name 'event' itself does not automatically mean 'asynchronous'.

Answer (score 1):

I think the name is OK. Eg Log4j has LoggingEvent class. It also makes sense  to consider an enum instead

```
enum LoggingEvent {
  NewFile,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses the same approach. Events objects are created in moment when user want to perform some action and then immediately are passed to event listener. It works
synchronous, so event object is used only to transfer some data.